# OpenGL Buffer Texture cache implementation

Tags: opengl, textures, opencl, gpu, gpgpu

I've been playing a bit with opengl TBOs today, because it seems to be the only way to have an object shared with OpenCL which OpenCL can read/write inside one kernel (it is not an image) and a fragment shader can read from (and has less limitation in size). Pretty nice!

However, after comparing the read performance on the GL side to actual 1d/2d/3d textures I have the suspicion the texelFetch on the gsamplerBuffer is simply and uncached global memory read, and for my application about **2x slower**. At least on OSX driver OpenGL 4.1 ATI-1.22.25, GLSL 4.10.

Can anybody confirm this suspicion or provide contrary findings (on other platforms?)?

Comment: Haha. That "edit". Sorry, I know it's bad form to say "thank you".